# Simple for statement program with user inputs

Tags: for-loop, input, char, subtraction

I'm having trouble getting my program to subtract a character the user inputted on the next line until it reaches zero. For example user inputs 5 for length and char Y the program should print five "Y" on first line then four "Y" on second..... until zero. like this...
ln(YYYYY)
ln(YYYY)
ln(YYY)
ln(YY)
ln(Y)
I cant get the program to go past the first line I would get:
ln(YYYYY
ln(Y)
ln(Y)
ln(Y)
ln(Y)

What I have:

```java
    int length;
    char d;     // tried using only char 'd' but scanner has a hard time with chars, so I used        String
    String UserChar;

    //scanner is needed
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //get user data and initialize variables
    System.out.println("Please input a positive whole number.");
    length = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please input one character.");
    UserChar = sc.next();
    sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();

    //do computation
    for(int a = length; a > 1 ; a = a - 1)  //prints user input on first line
    {
        System.out.print(UserChar);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i = i + 1)   //how many lines get printed
    {
        System.out.println(UserChar);
    }



    // print results (occurs in previous step)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you want to use nested loops. The first loop would control the length of what we print, then the second loop will just does the printing, based on the variable used in the first loop. For example:

```
//Gets how many chars to print going from n..1
for(int a = length; a >= 1 ; a = a - 1)  
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i = i + 1) //prints char a times
    {
        System.out.print(UserChar);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

[Here is an example](http://ideone.com/lDvf2T)